# Elmah produces error with web.config in localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, elmah

I set up Elmah in my development environment and when I try to access, what's im my case is "https://localhost:44381/elmah.axd" and I get the error:

"Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

And show the following lines in the web.config:

[image: Elmah produces error in web.config]

The line 39, securityPolicy voice is needed to the hosted application, if that's matter...

Sure enough I'm using IIS Express.

What happens here?

Comment: You can't set the security policy at anything but the root level is what the error tells you. In other words, it is a setting that can only apply to the full application, not a single file or directory.

Comment: @Mark Fitzpatrick it's exactly what you said... Don't you want to write it as an answer, instead of a comment, so that I can credit you?

Comment: I can understand why you thought that it was possible, though. The schema for config files says that it is a valid element :|